# How to access only a fragment from a layout?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, android-layout, apache-flex, flex4

I am having a layout with four Fragment layouts as shown below.
Now I need to access only two or three Fragments depending upon my selection which is from the database.

How to access only the desired Fragments?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.rknikhil.myapplication.fragment_sample">
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/list_Fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                class="com.example.rknikhil.myapplication.ProfileFragment" >
            </fragment>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/list_Fragment1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                class="com.example.rknikhil.myapplication.Notificationfragment">
            </fragment>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/list_Fragment2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                class="com.example.rknikhil.myapplication.ProfileFragment">
            </fragment>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/list_Fragment3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                class="com.example.rknikhil.myapplication.Notificationfragment" >
            </fragment>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can someone suggest me how to set a fragment class field from my mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

You can simple show and hide the fragment on the basis of the selection.
Use below code in OnCreateView() method . i.e

```
Fragment f= getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_Fragment);
Fragment f1= getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_Fragment1);
Fragment f2= getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_Fragment2);
f1.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I am getting a null exception error at f1.getview();

Comment: have you used the setContentView() to the layout before this code??